# Erro " An error occurred while processing your request. "

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, json, microsoft-azure

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em MVC C# para geração de relatórios em JSON, no meu `localhost` ele funciona normalmente, a *query* demora pois vare 2 a 3 bancos de dados dependendo do relatório, porém quando hospedei a aplicação no Azure, a maioria das vezes dá um erro

> "an error occurred while processing your request."

Às vezes ele faz sem problemas, estou suspeitando que seja algum *timeout* que tem configurado no painel da Azure, porém não achei essa opção no painel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desativei o customError e apareceu o erro real, aconteceu que por um descuido meu não fechei uma conexão, quando eu rodava local host ele funcionava, mais porque no local host funcionava e no azure não? bom é porque quando você testa em sua maquina você fecha o navegador no final do teste, assim fechando as conexões abertas, já no azure por outro lado ele não abre um navegador, ele faz a requisição e fica la, como não Havia fechado a conexão ele simplesmente deixava aberto assim excedendo o numero de conexões!

Answer (score 11):

A rede Azure supõe que o aplicativo que está subindo é de produção, portanto mensagens de Debug são desligadas por padrão. O jeito é habilitar manualmente a propriedade `customErrors` na configuração do seu projeto.

Configure o seu `Web.config` com o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Você quer dizer On em vez de Off?

Comment: Não, é Off mesmo. `customErrors` faz o .NET exigir do usuário que escreva uma tela de erro personalizada.

Comment: E setando pra Off ele vai mostrar a mensagem detalhada ou simplesmente omitir o erro?

Comment: Mostra a mensagem, a Stack Trace, dá alguns links...